# JavaScript if condition help

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have the followiing javascript if conditions in an .asp page:

```
<%@language="javascript"%>

var operator = new String("opstr")
operator.permissions = 2

if((operator.permissions & 1) == 1)
    // ... 
if((operator.permissions & 2) == 2)
    // ...
```

Can someone please explain what is happening in the if conditions listed above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

[Read the MDC article on Bitwise Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/operators/bitwise_operators)

`if((operator.permissions & 1) == 1)`

A bit wise equal. `1 & 1 === 1`, `2 & 1 === 0`, `3 & 1 === 1`

`if((operator.permissions & 2) == 2)`

Another bit wise equal `1 & 2 === 0`, `2 & 2 === 2`, `3 & 2 === 2`

Answer (score 3):

In this particular piece of code, the second `if` statement will always run. This is because `operator.permissions & 2` will always evaluate to `2` (since the variable is being set to `2` earlier on).

The `&` is a bit-wise `AND`. `2` is binary is `10` (in 32-bits it would be `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010`). When you do a bit-wise `AND` the values are converted into binary (signed 32-bit big endian) and each bit of one operand is `AND`ed with the other. When you `AND` two equal values, you get the same value as a result.

A few examples (I'm using 4-bit values here for readability):

```
1 & 1 = 0001 & 0001 = 0001 = 1
2 & 1 = 0010 & 0001 = 0000 = 0
3 & 1 = 0011 & 0001 = 0001 = 1
...
5 & 1 = 0101 & 0001 = 0001 = 1
```

and,

```
1 & 2 = 0001 & 0010 = 0000 = 0
2 & 2 = 0010 & 0010 = 0010 = 2
3 & 2 = 0011 & 0010 = 0010 = 2
...
6 & 2 = 0110 & 0010 = 0010 = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

These are bitwise operators. Read here: http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/bitwise_operators.html for more.